# How can I use google_sign_in with cognito

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, google-signin, amazon-cognito-facebook

I have flutter project and I use cognito for auth
and I use google_sign_in for login by google
how can I connect these serves together

is there anther way but without use web view